# How do I maintain aspect ratio when height is 100%?

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I have an iframe wrapped in a parent div, I know that the parent div and iframe are going to be 100% height of their parent (or the page).
Like this:

```
<div class="parent"> // will be 100% high
  <iframe></iframe> // will be 100% high & wide, pos absolute
</div>
```

How can I make the width of `parent` always maintain an aspect ratio?
In the same way that it is common to house iframe videos in a parent div with a `padding-top: 56.25%;` to maintain a 4:3 aspect ratio - how can I do this with width?

Comment: If the 100% you are using refers to the viewport height, then you can easily control the aspect ratio using `vh` units. For a 4:3 aspect ratio (landscape), then `100vh` for the height and then `133vh` for the width.

Comment: Hi Terry, that is exactly what I ended up doing and I don't know why it took me so long. Thanks anyway, I will upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

To further elabourate on my comment: if the 100% height you are referring to is the viewport height, then you can easily use `vh` units to fix the aspect ratio relative to viewport height.

For a 4:3 landscape-orientation ratio, the height is `100vh` and the width will be `calc(100vh / 3 * 4)`. You can also calculate it manually as `133vh` (technically 133.3333...).

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.parent {
  background-color: steelblue;
  height: 100vh;
  width: calc(100vh / 3 * 4);
  
  /* Presentation only */
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">4:3 ratio</div>
```